# What does "they prescribe upon our riper ears" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, quotes

I was searching for usages of the verb ***prescribe***, in conjunction with the preposition ***upon***, thinking the two of them might serve as a slightly milder alternative for *impose*, which indeed seems possible, judging from the scarce samples I found, one of whom is this:

> 'Tis sure a practice that savors much of pedantry; a reserve of puerility we have not shaken off from school; where, being seasoned with minor sentences, by a neglect of higher enquiries, they **prescribe upon** our riper
>   ears, and never are worn out, but with our memories.
>
> [[Sir Thomas
>   Browne](https://books.google.gr/books?id=OEr68dC6RLEC&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq="prescribe+upon"&source=bl&ots=ZrotJrHiYI&sig=fmmNmqSoYfqslaD_GHIt-WKErwo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZhrOY-c3QAhWDtRoKHQVrAQ0Q6AEIMTAI#v=onepage&q=%22prescribe%20upon%22&f=false)]
>
> [[Updates](https://books.google.com/books?id=2vEyAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=A+reserve+of+puerility+we+have+not+shaken+off+from+school,+where,+being+seasoned+with+minor+sentences,&source=bl&ots=7sVehlEEv3&sig=Rn402_7nm1aosz7ytau2P95cwLY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV6oGbq8_QAhVqslQKHYUqB6kQ6AEIKTAD#v=onepage&q=A%20reserve%20of%20puerility%20we%20have%20not%20shaken%20off%20from%20school%2C%20where%2C%20being%20seasoned%20with%20minor%20sentences%2C&f=false)]

---

I *think* I think it's brilliant, but I'm not really positive I'm interpreting it correctly.

Is it *"minor sentences"*, as in, say, *time that we are forced to serve*, that *teachers* (*"they"*) impose upon us during our riper years, and is it the same *minor sentences* **that** leave their mark, so to speak, until we've accumulated new memories through living?

And how is *"reserve"* meant? As a "stock" of puerility, so to speak, or as a puerile reluctance?

Comment: You will notice that it's "ears", not "years".  Verified by [this reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=x8VjAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=%22they+prescribe+upon+our+riper+ears%22&source=bl&ots=QF5k6fvcnz&sig=4K-MuzU5E5ksU47uIQOj093pM70&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK-8z8s8_QAhXqxFQKHYQxBDYQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=%22they%20prescribe%20upon%20our%20riper%20ears%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "practice" Browne deprecates is the habit of attributing self-evident truths to the authority of Classical rhetors and poets by quoting scraps of lesser works. This pedantry is something we retain (a *reserve*) from our schooling: in Browne's day students were expected to maintain a stock of these "minor sentences" (*sentence* with the sense of Latin *sententia*, "aphorism") to ornament their own written and spoken essays.

(Think of Hamlet hurrying to set down in his notebook what he has learned from the Ghost—*That one may smile and smile and be a villain*. As Horatio later observes, it needs no ghost come from the grave to tell us this sort of thing, which is more or less Browne's point, too.)

When we are grown, Browne says, the sentences we have memorized continue to *prescribe upon our ears* (serve as authoritative models for our judgment of texts), and only vanish from our consciousness when our memories fail (presumably in old age).

Comment: Ah, so it's sentences, as in _doctrines_, so to speak, but of scant value. (For a moment there I thought it was sentences, as in mere _time_ that we are _sentenced_ to serve, as in prison so in school...) And the _reserve_ is indeed meant as a "stock", IOW an accumulation of trivial concerns (_pedantry_),,, As for the _memories_, I think I initially misinterpreted them as the agent of "_wear out_" (as in _**by** our memories_), while they are merely meant as yet another thing whose "wearing out" will coincide _with_ that of the _minor sentences_. Right? [Nice answer, BTW]

Comment: @m.a.a.  I think Browne uses *sentences* mostly in the sense "pithy expression", though there are perhaps overtones of "doctrine". And the *memories* piece is more like "We can't escape the hold of the prescripts until we get old and forget them along with everything else".

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.  To "prescribe upon" can sort of be thought of as "directing upon/towards" by some sort of a preordained standard.

The idea seems to be that the practice that makes you enjoy being a know-it-all is an artefact of youth and immaturity (i.e. a reserve of puerility) which follows you into adulthood and after you've finished with your schooling.  It's a result of the fact that you end up absorbing trivia by neglecting serious and profound questions (i.e. you are seasoned with minor sentences, neglecting the higher enquiries) which are directed at/imposed upon young ears.  Then I guess that that creates an impression which only fades with age and experience.